# Postgresql CITEXT Datatype Issue JPA Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, postgresql, jpa, postgresql-9.1

I'm having difficulty using the CITEXT datatype in PostgreSQL using JPA and Hibernate. CITEXT is supposed to provide a case insensitive text datatype  but when used with JPA/Hibernate it doesn't behave in a case insensitive manner. Has anyone else had this issue or know a way around it? I have seen some mention (but very, very little) about a JDBC issue, but that went back at least a year and wasn't very clear.

I have a 'nickname' column defined as citext in postgres 9.1. I just did a test to see if it could find a row using a named query as such:

```
create table test(
    nickname citext
)

@NamedQuery(name = "Person.findByNickname", 
            query = "SELECT p 
                     FROM Person p 
                     WHERE p.nickname = :nickname")
```

Insert a nickname into the DB:

```
insert into test values('testNick')
```

Then run this code:

```
String nickname = "testNick";

Query q = em.createNamedQuery("Person.findByNickname");
q.setParameter("nickname", nickname);
if (q.getResultList().isEmpty()) {
    return (false);
}
return (true);
```

This returns 'true' (i.e. there is already a 'testNick' in the database).

If I make this assignment

```
String nickname = "testnick"; //(lower case 'N')
```

and run it again it returns 'false'.

Since the column is CITEXT, *it should return 'true'* again. i.e. case insensitive text.

Using JPA and Hibernate. Anyone have any thoughts?

In the meantime I've changed the column back to varchar and created a functional index for lowercase. And I have to create a native query now to search using database functions. Would like to find out if there is a way I can not have to do this to maintain the database abstraction.

Regards.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`citext` provides case-insensitive operators for use *within the database, with other citext values*.

### What's happening

At a guess, your JPA implementation is explicitly specifying the type of the parameter as `text` when it creates the parameterized statement. `citext` doesn't define a `citext = text` operator, so PostgreSQL casts the `citext` to `text` and uses the case-sensitive `text = text` operator. Effectively, comparing `citext` to `text` is case sensitive.

Here's what I think is happening. Given the dummy data:

```
regress=# CREATE EXTENSION citext;
regress=# CREATE TABLE citest ( x citext );
regress=# INSERT INTO citest(x) VALUES ('FRED'), ('FrEd');
regress=# SELECT * FROM citest;
  x   
------
 FRED
 FrEd
(2 rows)
```

... a comparison of citext to an unknown string literal will be interpreted as `citext=citext` and be done case-insensitively:

```
regress=# SELECT * FROM citest WHERE x = 'FRED';
  x   
------
 FRED
 FrEd
(2 rows)
```

... but a comparison between `citext` and an explicitly `text` typed literal will convert the `citext` argument to `text` using `citext`'s implicit cast to text, then do a `text=text` *case sensitive* comparison:

```
regress=# SELECT * FROM citest WHERE x = 'FRED'::text;
  x   
------
 FRED
(1 row)
```

Or rather, what Hibernate is doing will be closer to:

```
regress=# PREPARE blah(text) AS SELECT * FROM citest WHERE x = $1;
PREPARE
regress=# EXECUTE blah('FRED');
  x   
------
 FRED
(1 row)
```

where the type is specified as `text` when binding a parameter, since Hibernate "knows" that Strings are `text`.

In other words, you need to get Hibernate to, via PgJDBC, explicitly specify the `citext` datatype as the parameter type to your query, resulting in something like:

```
regress=# PREPARE blah(citext) AS SELECT * FROM citest WHERE x = $1;
PREPARE
regress=# EXECUTE blah('FRED');
  x   
------
 FRED
 FrEd
(2 rows)
```

Note the explicit `citext` type parameter to the prepared statement. That will be ... interesting ... to do, especially since PgJDBC doesn't know anything about the `citext` type. You'd have to write a custom data type handler for Hibernate that uses PgJDBC's `setObject`;  even then you'll have operator consistency issues between Java and Pg (see below).

IMO you'll be much better off using traditional case sensitive types and `lower()`, `ILIKE`, etc.

It's also possible that Hibernate is relying on what PgJDBC tells it about column case sensitivity. At least as of 9.2-devel PgJDBC doesn't know anything about the `citext` type, so it'll always say "yup, that's case sensitive" when asked.

### Tracing

It's hard to be sure that's what's happening without seeing the actual queries run by JPA. Try setting `log_statement = 'all'` in `postgresql.conf`. Then `SIGHUP` the postmaster, use `pg_ctl reload`, or restart Pg to cause the change to take effect.

Re-run your test and examine the logs. Test the queries you see in `psql` to observe the results. If you're unsure what's going on, update your question with them. If you update also include your Hibernate version and your PgJDBC version.

It's also possible that Hibernate is relying on what PgJDBC tells it about column case sensitivity. At least as of 9.2-devel PgJDBC doesn't know anything about the `citext` type, so it'll always say "yup, that's case sensitive" when asked.

### Operator consistency difficulties

**WARNING**: The `citext` type cannot affect how Hibernate works with the text once it's come out of the database. It won't have any effect on the `String.equals` method, for example. You would need to tell *Hibernate* you want it to treat the text as case insensitive. Otherwise if you have a `text` or `varchar` primary/foreign key you can get situations where the Hibernate asks for the key `"FRED"`, it gets `"FrEd"` back, and is quite confused because the DB returned a key that isn't equal - according to Hibernate - to the one it was asked for. Similar oddities will occur if you include `citext`-backed strings in `equals` and `hashCode` implementations in your entities.

Unfortunately JPA doesn't seem to specify annotation attributes in the `@Column` mapping for whether the column is case sensitive or not. Java [doesn't have the concept of a case-insensitive string data type](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/89949/what-are-the-pros-and-cons-of-having-a-caseinsensitivestring-type-in-java) anyway, so it wouldn't do tons of good even if JPA did specify it.

You'll probably avoid confusing Hibernate too badly so long as you don't use `citext` for keys or include `citext` values in `equals` and `hashCode`.

Comment: Good idea. It sounds like it is going to be a PITA to troubleshoot right now, so I'll just use the work around I mentioned. That is, use (lower) in a native query and use a functional index. I think that is what CITEXT does under the hood anyway.  Text and CITEXT by extension are just unbounded varchars anyway in Postgres, so it makes it a PITA but it is what it is. When I have some time I'll retest following your ideas vis a vis watching the logs (I've just commented out the problematic code so that I can do that).

Comment: @BillR Answer updated with a better explanation and more detail. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 13):

I am answering for the sake of future readers. The problem is that JDBC automatically casts String parameters to varchar, thus forcing comparison to be case-sensitive. This behavior can be changed by setting JDBC connection parameter "**stringtype**" to "**unspecified**".

If you are using JPA, put the following in your data source configuration:

```
<datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/testDS"
    pool-name="test" enabled="true"
    use-java-context="true" spy="true">
    <connection-url>jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres</connection-url>
    <driver>postgresql</driver>
    <connection-property name="stringtype">unspecified</connection-property>
    <security>
        <user-name>postgres</user-name>
        <password>******</password>
    </security>
</datasource>
```

Comment: Spring Boot users can use the following property: `spring.datasource.tomcat.connection-properties=stringtype=unspecified`


Thanks for sharing this!

Comment: In Spring Boot 2, use `spring.datasource.hikari.data-source-properties.stringtype=unspecified` if you're relying on the default Data Source which is now a Hikari connection pool

Comment: @mistahenry do you know the fix for r2dbc?

Comment: @A.Weatherwax do you know the fix for r2dbc?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answer by Craig Ringer, I understood that we should compare CITEXT with CITEXT. Casting the input as CITEXT worked for me (I tested in Spring Data JPA where the query is used under @Query(value = 'YOUR QUERY HERE', nativeQuery = true)

So, below should work as per my testing. It even uses index on nickname column if available (of course, it is up to the decision of query optimiser whether to use index or not)

```
@NamedQuery(name = "Person.findByNickname", 
            query = "SELECT p 
                     FROM Person p 
                     WHERE p.nickname = CAST(:nickname AS CITEXT)")
```